# Using OpenBLAS LAPACKE in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lapack, openblas, lapacke

i need some linear algebra in my project and want use OpenBLAS for this. I downloaded the precompiled version ([64bit version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.2.19/)) and unpacked it to my projectfolder. In Visual Studio, i added include-, bin-, and lib-folder to my Project and ran the this [example](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/User-Manual#code-examples) without problems.

Next, i wanted to look at LAPACK, so i added lapacke.h to the includes, which is in the same directory as cblas.h and is included in the official download. But now i get hundreds of errors, for every function, as if a lib file was missing or something. E.g. for this line

```
85 lapack_complex_float lapack_make_complex_float( float re, float im );
```

i get

```
PATH\include\lapacke.h(85): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'lapack_make_complex_float'
```

I can't find any further information on how to set up OpenBLAS/LAPACK, they usually just say 'include the files', which i have. Otherwise the cblas example wouldn't run either. And the (relevant) examples i can find only use cblas.h, not lapacke.h

Can some tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason my 'Hello' at the beginning is missing and can't be added using edit. so HELLO and does someone know why it's missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that OpenBlas uses C99 _Complex by default. This is not supported by Visual C++. You can solve this by using standard library definitions before including lapacke.h:

```
#include <complex>
#define lapack_complex_float std::complex<float>
#define lapack_complex_double std::complex<double>
#include <lapacke.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using std::complex is problematic unless OpenBLAS was built with LAPACK_COMPLEX_CPP otherwise the library uses a different complex type internally, usually C99 _Complex.

Modern versions of the Microsoft compiler (e.g. the one in VSTUDIO 2022) support a similar "_Complex" mechanism. Therefore I include the following header file prior to "lapacke.h"

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER

#include <complex.h>

#define LAPACK_COMPLEX_CUSTOM

typedef _Dcomplex lapack_complex_float;
typedef _Fcomplex lapack_complex_double;

#define lapack_complex_float_real(z)       (real(z))
#define lapack_complex_float_imag(z)       (imag(z))

#endif // _MSC_VER
```

See the lapack.h header file that ships with OpenBLAS how #define LAPACK_COMPLEX_CUSTOM overrides complex variable type definitions

Comment: Just wanted to add that you swapped the _Dcomplex->float and _Fcomplex->double above, if you could edit it for the next person that would help!